# Use dp width in PercentRelativeLayout

Tags: android, density-independent-pixel, android-percentrelativelayout

When I try to add a view without "widthPercent" or "heightPercent" in a [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html), the view doesn't show up.

The reason why I want this is to add a divider between the 2 elements of my [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) with a width of 1dp.

The layout I use is this :

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_list_container"
        app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/divider"/>

     <View android:id="@id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/detailed_list_divider"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fragment_details_container"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fragment_details_container"/>

     <FrameLayout android:id="@id/fragment_details_container"
         app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"

         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/base_activity_padding"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/base_activity_padding"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/base_activity_padding" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

And if I set "layout_widthPercent" to 1% at my divider it will show up. But I want it to take only 1dp. Is their a way to achieve this?

Thank's !

Comment: I don't think so dp will work here, but you can use percent as like 0.01% for view and 0.99% for below frame, it will help you

Comment: When I set 0.01% the divider is not shown on some device (maybe 0.01% is less than 1dp).

Comment: You have applied right way above so keep it, it is also fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to achieve my goal but I don't really like it (not very clean) so I post it here and if no one gives me any better solution I will add it as an answer.

What I've done is to add a RelativeLayout with a widthPercent of 1% that containing my view of 1dp. Like this :

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_list_container"
        app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/divider"/>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/divider"
        app:layout_widthPercent="1%"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fragment_details_container"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fragment_details_container">

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/detailed_list_divider" />

     </RelativeLayout>

     <FrameLayout android:id="@id/fragment_details_container"
         app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"

         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/base_activity_padding"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/base_activity_padding"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/base_activity_padding" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if you have any better idea.